# ApexChart destroy and unattend render again

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, apexcharts

I've create ASP.Net core solution and some details of item will be displayed in bootstrap modal as chart (apexChart library). Chart appear correctly when modal shows, destroy method seems to be works fine as well on modal hidden, but apex chart div occurs again in DOM when modal 'on hidden' action complete.
Below you can see my code for modal shows and hidden:

```
$(function () {
     // on show modal
    $('#detailsInfoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

        let button = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var url = button.attr('url');
        var itemId = button.attr('itemName');
        let itemName = button.attr('resourcename');
        let itemType = button.attr('resourcetype');
        let subscriptionName = button.attr('subscriptionname');
        SetModalTitle(true, itemName);
        SetModalSubtitle(true, "Type: " + itemType + ", subscription: " + subscriptionName);

        $.get(url, { id: itemId, period: "LastMonth" }, function (data) {
            ShowModalChartLoaders(false);        
            GetSingleLineApexChart(data);
        });
    });

    // on hide modal
    $("#detailsInfoModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        ApexCharts.exec('resourceSingleLineChart', 'destroy', {});
    });
});
```

The situation is the same for Edge and Mozilla firefox.
I've trying to remove all child divs by jquery, but apex div still persist.